# Unable to install JSQMessengerViewController as a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am currently using xCode 6 and running on iOS 8. I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) to my project but I have ran into some problems, specifically where the instructions tell me to use

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

to install the library. I get the error code in my terminal:

```
[!] Unknown command: `JSQMessagesViewController`
```

What am I doing wrong? I have updated and installed cocoa pods with

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

Now when I run pod setup, Setup completed was returned along with:

```
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
```

I'm not sure if this changes anything or affects me installing the pod.

Comment: What is the output of the `pod repo update --verbose` from that error message?